# How to get sibiling-nodes in XML or in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a big .xml file. As you see I uploaded a part of it as a picture. As an example I marked a part of it which I need to detect using Xpath or XSLT. The Xpath or XSLT code must go through the whole .xml file and find any case(s) when (IsNewNode="True") and (Removed="True") belong to the same node (for example as represented in the pic both belongs to the ) **and** also both are sibilings which means both have the same 'Id' value (again as an example in both the Id="KANAL").
[Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9DX3.png)

I have **'//*[@IsNewNode="True" and @Removed="True"]'** xpath. But It only works when both (IsNewNode="True" and Removed="True") located in one line like here : [Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JmUA.png)

But I need to cover the case I presented in the question.

Comment: It's better to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42645123/edit) the question and put there the XML example.

Comment: What does "Find the existence" mean? Please show the relevant part of your XSLT code.

Comment: @SarehGhayoomi Please show us the XSLT you currently have and which part of it you'd like to change. With the current wording of your question, it's hard to know how to help you.

Comment: I have 
'//*[@IsNewNode="True" and @Removed="True"]' xpath. 
But It only works when both (IsNewNode="True" and Removed="True") located in one line like here :
<Item Id="Oracle_Schedule_ListView" Index="5" ObjectKey="" ViewId="Oracle_Schedule_ListView" Visible="True" IsNewNode="True" Removed="True"/>
But I need to cover the case I presented in the question.

Comment: You want to get `Items` element or both `PropertyEditor` elements?

Comment: You need to take some time to familiarize yourself with how this site works. Please don't post code into the comments. Edit your question. Format it properly. It's not hard to learn, but you need to take five minutes and learn it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that in `XPath` `"Kanal" != "KANAL"`! Edit your question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Use for-each on the node 'Items/PropertyEditor'
Not an xslt expert here.
So NOT AN OPTIMAL CODE, I think

```
<xsl:variable name="RemovedTrueFound">
<xsl:for-each select="Items/PropertyEditor">
    <xsl:if test="(./@Id = 'KANAL') and (./@Removed='True')">
            <xsl:value-of select="found" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="IsNewNodeTrueFound">
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/PropertyEditor">
        <xsl:if test="(./@Id = 'KANAL') and (./@IsNewNode='True')">
                <xsl:value-of select="found" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="($RemovedTrueFound = 'found') and ($IsNewNodeTrueFound = 'found')>
    existence found
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need to generalize it for any value for 'Id'. That means that 'Id' can have any other value like 'KANAL' . Is that possible in XSLT?

Comment: <xsl:variable name='EverChangingId'>
set value here
</xsl:variable>.....
and replace 'KANAL' with $EverChangingId

Answer (score 0):

Try below `XPath` expression:

```
//Items[PropertyEditor[@Id="KANAL" and @IsNewNode="True"] and  PropertyEditor[@Id="KANAL" and @Removed="True"]]
```

**UPDATE**

If you need your `XPath` to match `Items` that contains two `PropertyEditor` child-elements with same **any** values of `Id` attribute, than you can try

```
//Items[PropertyEditor[@IsNewNode="True"]/@Id=./PropertyEditor[@Removed="True"]/@Id]
```

This will check whether `Id` of `<PropertyEditor IsNewNode="True" Id>` is just the same as `Id` of  `<PropertyEditor Removed="True" Id>` without specifying its actual value

Comment: This works fine, Thanks a lot. But I need to generalize it for any value for 'Id'. That means that 'Id' can have any other value like 'KANAL' . The value is not a fixed one, acctually this is a variable. I think there is not such a possibility to work with different variables in Xpath. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dividing the condition into two nested conditions

1. select all nodes with IsNewNode='True'
2. for nodes from step 1. check the @Removed attribute.

Note that 2 cases: node has @Removed attribute or a sibling with equal @Id has @Removed attribute can be combined into one: parent has a child with @Id equal to current node and @Removed attribute.

Here is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="//PropertyEditor[@IsNewNode='True']">
 <xsl:if test="../PropertyEditor[@Id = current()/@Id and @Removed='True']">
    <a><xsl:value-of select="@Id" /></a>
 </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```